# how to use js to jump to a specific element like using hashes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm looking for a way that lets me jump to a specific element in a list of elements (divs) using javascript.

I can't use hashes, because i'm using the history.js plugin to display the position as if it was a url (http://www.mysite.com/load/php/into/div/)

I've tried scrolltop() and the scrollto plugin, but both won't let me jump directly to an element - I don't want the the page to flicker, as the scrollbar goes down.

I'm looking for a way that would look just as if you would be using linked hashes to get to the element.

Comment: @JamesMontagne I think he need minimum of 15 rep to accept an answer. Not sure.

Comment: @vega I'm pretty sure that's not the case.  Would be rather silly.  I don't see it listed in the list of privileges so I'm fairly certain everyone can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this to jump to an element using scrollTo jQuery plugin.

```
var $parent = $('someParentContainer');//Or you can use body element
var $target = $parent.find('elementToScrollTo');
$('body').scrollTo($target, 500);
```

Comment: He doesn't want to use scrollTo.

Comment: The reason he is not using `scrollTo` is because he could not jump to an element using `scrollTo` but it can be achieved.

Comment: Isn't that 2nd parameter a duration?  He doesn't want to animate the scroll, he just wants to go straight to it.  Not sure why `scrollTop` wouldn't work though.

Comment: Yes that is for animation. We can set it to `0` or I guess we can just ignore it if we don't need animation. With `scrollTop` you have to find the position of the element to scroll to so using `scrollTo` plugin it will do everything.

Comment: even when using .scrollTo($target,0) there is a short page flicker, when it's going from entry #1 to entries at the bottom of the page in my site - i will create a jsfiddle for this later, if it's a problem with the code and actually something that can be done with scrollto

Comment: finally got it to work, for some reason i had to specify the sync like this (example with top of page): $('body').scrollTo(0,0;);